# Dispatcherservlet force loading spring context

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, web.xml

I developed a web application in spring and observed that beans are loading two times while starting the server.

1. Please let me know why is this behaviour and advise if there is anything wrong in configuration.
2. I understand that on providing the load-on-startup as 1, the beans will be loaded during context loading. But, why does the same beans load even when application war file is deployed? Currently, I see the beans loading twice during context initialization and then when the WAR file is getting deployed.

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PizzaRest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.pizza.resource,
            com.pizza
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.disableMoxyJson.server</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pizzaservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:pizza-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PizzaRest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pizzaservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pizzaservlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

While loading the server, I see beans are loading twice.

```
    Jun 10, 2015 8:49:27 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 746 ms
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [pizza-context.xml]
    Jun 10, 2015 8:49:36 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader    initWebApplicationContext
    INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 460 ms
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [servlet-context.xml]
```

Comment: No they aren't. That are 2 different contexts, one is the `DispatcherServlet` the other is the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you say the behavior in my use case is as expected?

Comment: Yes because you either have 2 servlets loading different files or have a `ContextLoaderListener` and a servlet (or multiple) all of these create their own `ApplicationContext`.